# ROS Answers SE migration: start amcl

Tags: navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This thelauch file that consider the amcl package

Can I use this to start the amcl package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38635/start-amcl/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2012-07-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-07-12**:
Ok. So I have a installed and build a group of packages , between them the amcl packages. But would like to run the amcl node only. So I have only one lauch file for the whole package system. So dont have a launch file for the amcl package. Can I use the lauch file for the whole system?

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-07-16**:
Hello. I wanted to edit more lines of the launch file  but could not. Icould edit only only one line. What is the problem?? please any help? why was not let to edit the whole launch file???

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-07-17**:
where is placed this package turtlebot_navigation/config/amcl_turtlebot??? I can not find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please have a look at the [amcl wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/amcl) and some sample configuration files. For instance, the amcl configuration for the Turtlebot can be found in the package `turtlebot_navigation/config/amcl_turtlebot.launch`. You probably won't be able to use that amcl launch file out of the box because some topics might not match, i.e. you'll maybe need to fix the topic remapping.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1